# not subscriptable error when trying to subscript

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

We begin with a user inputted string containing only lower-case letters

```
for letter in encoded_input:
        if letter == ' ':
            decoded_output.append(' ')
            continue
        
        decoded_output.append(map_input(letter,tpos1,tpos2,tpos3))
```

and then pass to this function

```
def map_input(value,r1,r2,r3,wr=wiring,rf=reflector):#Use reflector as well
    pass1 = rf[r3[r2[r1[wr[ALPH.index(value)]]]]]
    r1,r2,r3 = reverse_rotors(r1,r2,r3)
    return ALPH[wr[r1[r2[r3[pass1]]]]]
```

where all of the variables passed are lists containing numbers 0-25 in a unique arrangement.

## Problem

When I do this, however, I get an error telling me

```
pass1 = rf[r3[r2[r1[wr[ALPH.index(value)]]]]]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Am I missing the obvious or is something subtle going on? Value is indeed a lower case letter in ALPH (which is just a list containing the alphabet).

Comment: But you **are trying to subscript! 5 times in the same line!** You should change the question title, so it reflects reality.

Comment: Pardon? None of those things are ints? They are all lists?

Comment: I don't know what they are, since you didn't provide any of them. ([\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). You **claim** that all are lists, but interpreter contradicts you. I tend to believe the latter. Try adding a *print* statement before the faulty line, e.g. (`print(type(rf), type(r3), type(r2), ...)`) to see which one is not an iterable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error means that you tried to do `foo[bar]` where `foo` is an integer.  Something like this

```
x = 1
x[0]
```

will reproduce the error.
So here, one of reflector,letter,tpos1,tpos2,tpos3, or wiring is an integer.

Comment: Right. That's what I initially checked. Thing is, none of them are.

Comment: add a `print` statement right before the line that errors, to print out each of the 5 values.

Comment: Yeah, found it. Another method was overwriting this without me knowing. Thanks!